# Signed finite Radon measures with vague topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory

If $X$ is a locally compact and $\sigma$-compact metric space. Let $M(X)$ be the space of signed finite Radon measures on $X$.

(1) Show that measures with finite support is dense is $M(X)$ in the vague topology.

(2) Show that a probability measure in $M(X)$ is the vague limit of a sequence of finitely supported probability measures.

---

Don't know how to get started. Any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution adapts the proof in Heinz Bauer's *Measure and Integration Theory*.

For the first item, fix $\mu \in M(X)$ and without loss of generality take $\mu$ to be unsigned (taking components later resolves this).  Fix an open ball $V$ of $\mu$ in the vague topology, say, $V$ is the intersection of balls under the seminorms $\mu(f_1), \dots, \mu(f_n)$ with radius $\epsilon$, for $f_1, \dots, f_n \in C_c(X \to \mathbb{R})$ nonzero.  Then $$K := \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^n \text{supp }(f_j)$$ is compact.  Fix $\eta$ such that $\eta \mu(K) < \epsilon$.  Then every $y \in K$ belongs to an open neighborhood $U_y$ with $|f_j (x) - f_j(z)| \le \eta$  for all $x, z \in U_y$, $j = 1, \dots, n$.  Cover $K$ with finitely many such neighborhoods, say $k$ of them.  Set $$ A_1 := K \cap U_{y_1},$$ and proceeding inductively, $$A_j := K \cap U_j \setminus (A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_{j-1}).$$  These gives a pairwise disjoint collection of relatively compact Borel sets whose union is $K$, and for all $y', y'' \in A_i$, $|f_j(y') - f_j(y'')| \le \eta$ for $j = 1, \dots, n$.  Without loss of generality, we can take each $A_i$ to be nonempty, and pick $x_i \in A_i$ for each $i$.  Then $$\nu := \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \mu(A_i) \delta_{x_i}$$ is a discrete measure that lies in $V$:

$$ | \int_X f_j d\mu - \int_X f_j d\nu| = |\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \int_{A_i} (f_j - f_j(x_i))d\mu| \le \eta \mu(K) \le \epsilon.$$  This completes the proof.

For the second item, note that for a probability measure $\mu$ we already have for any vaguely open $V$ containing $\mu$, a discrete measure $\nu \in V$.  However, we can pick a probability measure $\nu' \in V$ by taking $x_0 \not\in K$ as defined in the construction of $\nu$ and set $\nu(x_0) = 1 - \nu(X \setminus x_0)$.  $\nu(X) \le 1$ by monotonicity, so this construction gives a discrete probability measure.  Then $\nu'$ is a probability measure and $\nu' \in V$, so we are done.

Comment: Very nice proof! Thank you so much!